# How to periodically run a script on Azure App Service filesystem (logs deletion)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice

I know I can delete old files manually but I need to automate the process. Some cron script would do the job but as far as I know when the app service will be reproviosioned my changes will be lost.

The App Service runs Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by default, logs are not automatically deleted (with the exception of Application Logging (Filesystem)). To automatically delete logs, set the Retention Period (Days) field (it's one of the way to do that).

You could automate the deletion by leveraging KUDU Virtual File System (VFS) Rest API. For a sample script, checkout this [discussion thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#javascript-example) for a similar approach.

While WebJobs is not yet supported for App Service on Linux.You could use Azure Functions for running scripts, if your requirement [fits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#javascript-example).

Comment: Thanks, but how azure function can access app service filesystem??